# Find out the Metadata of PDF file by using PDF Printer

Tags: pdf

I installed a PDF Printer on Linux Ubuntu version,so whenever i print any document the PDF Printer generates the .PDF file,Now I wants to find out the metadata of the generated pdf file when i will give print to any document.Is there any chance,please let me know.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the best PDF metadata viewer for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401114/which-is-the-best-pdf-metadata-viewer-for-ubuntu)

Comment: my question is when i click on "print" button the pdf printer generates   the .pdf files at same time i wants to generate the metadata of that generated pdf when i click on "print" button

Comment: If you can view the pdf data, then copy the metadata into LibreOffice Writer and save it as a pdf document. Then install PDF-Shuffler from the Ubuntu Software Center and merge the original pdf and the pdf metadata together into a new combined pdf. PDF-Shuffler treats each pdf page as a card in a deck of cards, and you can deal the "cards" in any order by dragging them around. Then print the new combined pdf document. I hope this helps.

Comment: how i can merge that two pdf's,i installed pdftk still it is not working

Comment: pdftk is the hard way to merge PDFs. Try PDF-Shuffler instead of pdftk, it's much easier. To add a new pdf document in PDF-Shuffler, just click on the green plus sign.

Comment: i installed pdf-shuffler also,but where i can find that and how can i work that one for merging the pdf's

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pdfinfo` from Terminal:

```
pdfinfo MyThesis.pdf
```

You will get results like this:

```
Title:          Analysis of Markov chains
Subject:        
Keywords:       thesis, masters, cal poly
Author:         **************
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.14
CreationDate:   Tue Jun 10 21:44:48 2014
ModDate:        Tue Jun 10 21:44:48 2014
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          99
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      10321297 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

(If you are using `cups-pdf` you can run an automated postprocessing command by uncommenting and editing  `cups-pdf.conf`'s `"PostProcessing"`  section. Since the question is unclear about this part, I cannot give more details.)

Comment: Hi Frantique above command is working good through terminal,but i want whenever i will give print any document it will genertes the .pdf and at the same time i want metadata of that pdf file.

Comment: @SrinivasB So you want to print out the data that `pdfinfo` gives you? Just do that then. Perhaps `pdfinfo MyThesis.pdf > infofile` then print `infofile`

Comment: @Xen2050 thats good,but i want when i click on print button generate metadata of that .pdf also

Comment: @SrinivasB: see revised answer.

Comment: @  Frantique where i a can find this cups-pdf.conf's "PostProcessing" in ubuntu

Comment: Where conf files resides: in /etc directory. If you are not familiar with linux, please ask a professional to help you in place.

Comment: @ Frantique:is it enough for just uncommenting "PostProcessing" in cups-pdf.conf'

Comment: @Xen2050:pdfinfo MyThesis.pdf > infofile this command didnt give creation date and modified dtae

Comment: It should just redirect stdout into the file `infofile`, works for nearly every command line program. I didn't think `pdfinfo` would send it's output to stderr but it's possible... maybe something else is going on

Comment: @ Frantique:i uncommented "postprocessing" in cups-pdf.conf,but it is not working

Comment: Did you added any command there?

Comment: @ Frantique:No,need to add any command,please let me know

Comment: Think a little bit: you told to cups to execute a postprocessing command, but you didn't told him what to do. Add: `pdfinfo "$1" > $1.txt` for example. That will hopefully make a txt file in the same location where it is the pdf.

Comment: @ Frantique:i added pdfinfo "$1" > $1.txt command in cups-pdf.conf,below postprocessing,when i print a file it didn't produce the text file

Comment: @SrinivasB: please learn at least some Bash scripting.

Comment: @ Frantique:yes