# How to remove all metadata from a file (e.g. pdf)?

Tags: pdf, metadata, exif

For privacy concerns, I want to remove all metadata from a document (e.g. **pdf**, **jpg**, **docx**, …). Metadata in general is additional information stored somehow apart the actual content like:

- Used Software
- Used Operating System
- Time and sometimes place
- Camera model, used gear… (photographs, see [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format))
- …

How do I reliably strip all metadata from my **pdf**, **jpg**, **docx**, etc., files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and remove meta (exif) data from my photos using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260810/how-can-i-read-and-remove-meta-exif-data-from-my-photos-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF metadata viewer / tag editor for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401114/)

Comment: @PabloBianchi and karel: Both links refer to different questions. The former one seeks a metadata editor and the latter a metadata removal regarding just photographs. The question here is meant in respect of _privacy_ regarding a _general_ file and the _abstract_ concept of metadata. That is: (1) Metadata is not necessarily an editable field and (2) I do not seek to edit, but to just strip it.
I changed some words above to make the distinction more clear.

Answer (score 6):

## MAT

Have a look at [MAT](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2) (*Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit*)! It comes from the [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/)-people and as standard on [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)—a privacy and anonymity focused live OS.

Since it's kind of a wrapper around `exiftool`, it supports more file [formats that `exiftool`](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#supported) alone.

By now, they are:

- Portable Network Graphics (.png)
- JPEG (.jpg, .jpeg, …)
- TIFF (.tif, tiff, …)
- Open Documents (.odt, .odx, .ods, …)
- Office OpenXml (.docx, .pptx, .xlsx, …)
- Portable Document Fileformat (.pdf)
- Tape ARchives (.tar, .tar.bz2, …)
- MPEG AUdio (.mp3, .mp2, .mp1, …)
- Ogg Vorbis (.ogg, …)
- Free Lossless Audio Codec (.flac)
- Torrent (.torrent)

For some more details, have a look at [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3648) paper.

### BEWARE

> “Mat only removes standard metadata from your files, it does *not*:
>
> - anonymise their content
> - handle watermarking
> - handle [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)
> - any overly customized metadata field/system (→jpg,zip)
>
> If you really want to be anonymous, use formats that do not contain any metadata, or better: use plain-text.
>
> And most important, be careful: every format can be watermarked, even plain text (e.g. the SNOW project)!
>
> You can also print out a copy of the documents, re-scan them, and pass it to the MAT; but be careful to securely shred your printout and not leave traces in your printer’s/scanner’s memory.”
>   (taken from [MAT-website](https://mat.boum.org/))

#### JPEG

Comments and the standard Exif-/IPTC-/XMP-tags are being deleted.
There might be proprietary non-standard tags (like Canon Raw tags) MAT does not touch. These could be included by e.g. proprietary RAW → JPEG conversion tools.

#### ZIP

MAT does not alter the content of the archive. If a tool creates additional files containing metadata within the archive, they will not be touched.

### Installation

#### Ubuntu 12.10 and above

Since Ubuntu 12.10 it's in the standard repository *universe*.

sudo apt install mat

#### Below Ubuntu 12.10

For older versions of Ubuntu, it has to be installed by hand. The dependencies are:

- gir1.2-poppler-0.18
- libimage-exiftool-perl (universe)
- python2.7
- python-gi-cairo
- python-mutagen
- python-pdfrw (universe)

Install them via:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-poppler-0.18 libimage-exiftool-perl python2.7 python-gi-cairo python-mutagen python-pdfrw
```

Then get MAT [here](https://mat.boum.org/files/) (e.g. mat-0.6.1.tar.xz). If you want verify your download with [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/), get the .asc file as well.

To check it, import the key given at the bottom of the page e.g. via

```
gpg --search-keys 0x04D041E8171901CC
```

and check with:

```
gpg --verify mat-0.6.1.tar.xz.asc  mat-0.6.1.tar.xz
```

The output should be something like

```
gpg: Signature made Sun 03 Jan 2016 09:02:29 PM CET using RSA key ID 171901CC
gpg: Good signature from "Julien (jvoisin) Voisin <julien.voisin@dustri.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Julien (jvoisin) Voisin <jvoisin@riseup.net>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Julien (jvoisin) Voisin <jvoisin@openmailbox.net>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 9FCD EE9E 1A38 1F31 1EA6  2A74 04D0 41E8 1719 01CC
```

Extract and install via

```
tar xvfJ mat-0.6.1.tar.xz
cd mat-0.6.1
sudo python2 setup.py install
```

Debian users find it in the *testing*-repo, Arch users in [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/).

If everything went fine, you have the console tool `mat` as well as the gui `mat-gui`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had to look this up multiple times now, here is the solution that worked for me for pdfs:

```
pdftk myfile.pdf cat 1-end output clean-myfile.pdf
```

This here also looks sensible (but I did not test it):

```
qpdf --pages myfile.pdf 1-z -- --empty clean-myfile.pdf
```

both answers are taken from https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6078384#gistcomment-2004771 .

Comment: Did you even check if the pdftk output is clean? A simple `strings clean-myfile.pdf` clearly shows pdftk puts its own trash in there: `/Creator (pdftk-java ...`.