# App for deleting PDF metadata?

Tags: pdf, metadata, desktop-apps

I was using the excellent app MAT (Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit) to delete PDF metadata but recently MAT stopped working for some reason and whenever I try to use it on .pdf files it reports:

[-] Unable to process .pdf

Also, on the MAT webpage, it says maintenance and development is currently on hold. So I guess this is why it stopped working.

I have looked at some other options like exiftool but this states outright that "original metadata is never actually removed."

Apps like exiv2 do not work on .pdf files.

I need to remove .pdf file metadata as a requirement for work. I prefer using linux, but I must have this capability for work so I'm trying to avoid having to use Windows.

Now that MAT is no longer supported, are there any other options?

Comment: My answer using `pdftk` or `qpdf`:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1300265/632237